# blank white page in admin, white space hunting?

Tags: admin, errors, fatal-error

Upon logging into the dashboard, I am presented with a blank white page, tho the front end of the site works fine. I am pretty sure its due to a white space oposed to a plugin issue, but not sure where the white space could be hiding, I have checked wp-config and functions to no avail, any way to sniff them out?

Thanks!

Comment: If you suspect it's a plugin issue, you could rename your plugins directory via FTP and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I'm 99% sure it's mot a plugin issue, so I am trying to find out if its a white space issue, if theres anyway to hunt for white spaces easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your seeing is probably a PHP fatal error, however your server will be configured to log them to the error log rather than present it on the frontend.

To find out what the error is, check your error log, or alternatively, if you don't have access to the error log or enabling the error log is not an option, you could enable printing the errors to the frontend. This will give you a blank page but now there will be a PHP error message. You will not want to do this in a production environment, and you won't want to enable this for very long if you're forced into that situation.

One way of doing this is by enabling WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php. How you would enable error logging to the screen is a subject for another question

Comment: Thanks, I have see the errors, one is due to the memory limit, any idea how I can change it without admin access?